# Running Windows 7 in a VM for tinkering

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, disk-image, development

Is there any kind of dev edition VM image of Windows 7 to play around with to avoid messing up my normal install?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a 90 eval of Windows 7 Enterprise [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx).  I am not aware of any developer editions, or anything specific to running inside a VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can get images of WinXP or Vista (intended for testing various versions of IE) that expire after a period of time: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Microsoft currently updates these as the old ones expire - I'm not sure how long they'll continue to do that.

But as far as I know there's nothing similar with Win7 - you'd need to just install a demo version (or your own licensed version) in a VM. You can use any of the normal channels to get an install image (TechNet, MSDN, MAPS, retail, whatever)